# Nuxt auth module fails to login

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

What I'm doing is a mobile application using Nuxt and Capacitor.

Since the Nuxt Auth module doesn't support in app dialogs for oAuth authentications, what I'm trying to do is to mix the `capacitor-google-auth` with the Auth module.

I perform correctly the oAuth login with Google and I can get the credentials.

Then I force the Auth Module to set its strategy to Google in this way (following their documentation)

```
// method 1
this.$auth.$storage.setUniversal('strategy', 'google')
this.$auth.strategy.token.set(token)
const user = await this.$auth.fetchUser()
await this.$auth.setUser(user)

// method 2
this.$auth.$storage.setUniversal('strategy', 'google')
await this.$auth.setUserToken(token)
```

I can correctly see the calls to my API in both ways, the user get fetched correctly the first time.

Unfortunately the token in both the cookie and local storage is not set, or better, it is set for a millisecond, then it get cleared...

Once completed the process the `try catch` get an error and it is `undefined`.

Do you know how can I let it work? Do you need more information?

Thanks

EDIT: Adding `auth` configuration:

```
auth: {
    resetOnError: true,
    localStorage: false,
    cookie: {
      prefix,
      options: {
        maxAge,
        secure: true,
        domain,
      },
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/',
      logout: '/',
      home: '/home',
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/auth/local',
            method: 'POST',
            propertyName: 'token',
          },
          logout: { url: '/auth/logout', method: 'POST' },
          user: { url: '/me', method: 'GET', propertyName: false },
        },
        tokenRequired: true,
        tokenType: 'Bearer',
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: Could you please share your `nuxt.config.js` ? (`nuxt-auth` section)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize that you authorize your user with google OAuth2 and receive a token from Google, and you want to store that. I had the same issue; after registering a user, I wanted to keep the user logged in. So in my case, I receive the token from register API and then use `nuxt-auth` to set the tokens.

Here is my code after the user registers:

```
try {
    this.$bvToast.hide('register-error-toast')
    let response = await this.$axios.post('/api/auth/register/', this.user_data)

    // these two methods are what you can try

    this.$auth.setUser(response.data.user)
    this.$auth.setUserToken(response.data.token)
} catch (error) {

}
```

And this is my `auth` config in the `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
auth: {
    redirect: {
        login: '/auth/login',
        logout: '/',
        home: '/'
    },
    cookie: {
        options: {
            maxAge: 12 * 24 * 60 * 60
        }
    },
    strategies: {
        local: {
            autoFetchUser: false,
            token: {
                property: 'token',
                type: 'Bearer'
            },
            user: {
                property: 'user',
                autoFetch: false
            },
            endpoints: {
                login: {
                    url: process.env.BASE_URL + '/api/auth/login/',
                    method: 'post'
                },
                user: false,
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I shared my whole config with you, and it may have some excessive data; you can change the config base on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it now.

Comment: With some extra coding I managed to let it work following your hint! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad that it helped :)